# Using django modeling, how do you properly extend a model?

Tags: python, django

I'm an amateur developer who has been learning python in order to build my first full-stack project, which is an animal exchange site for a game I play. The animals can have up to 3 traits, but some of them have special ones. In the case of animals with special traits, I attempted to extend the base model and add additional traits using a notation someone suggested, but it doesn't seem to work. I know that technically I can just copypaste the base trait set and manually add them in, with a different model every time but that seems like it would bloat my code, and I'd like to be efficient about it. If you notice something else that could be improved, please let me know, thanks.

```
    from django.db import models
#traits listed in class animal are base traits
class ANIMAL(models.Model):
    MALE = 'MA'
    FEMALE = 'FE'
    SHINY = 'SHI'
    NORMAL = 'NOR'
    EGG = 'EGG'
    CHILD = 'CHI'
    ADOLESCENT = 'ADO'
    ADULT = 'ADU'
    ELDER = 'ELD'
    BIGBONED = 'BIGB'
    BUTTERFACE = 'BUTT'
    CHARMED = 'CHAR'
    CHATTY = 'CHAT'
    CONSTIPATED = 'CONS'
    CURVY = 'CURV'
    EVIL = 'EVIL'
    EXALTED = 'EXAL'
    FORTUNATE = 'FORT'
    FREAKOFNATURE = 'FREA'
    FROSTBREATH = 'FROS'
    FUSSYEATER = 'FUSS'
    GENETICINFERIORITY = 'GINF'
    GENETICINSTABILITY = 'GINS'
    GENETICMUTATION = 'GENM'
    GENIUS = 'GENI'
    GIVER = 'GIVE'
    GLISTENING = 'GLIS'
    GOLDENGIFT = 'GOLD'
    GOOD = 'GOOD'
    GOODBREEDING = 'GOOB'
    HANDSOME = 'HAND'
    HYPERACTIVE = 'HYPE'
    IMMUNE = 'IMMU'
    INSANE = 'INSA'
    JOVIAL = 'JOVI'
    JOYFUL = 'JOYF'
    LIMITEDEFFICIENCY = 'LIMI'
    LITHE = 'LITH'
    LUCKY = 'LUCK'
    MYSTERIOUS = 'MYST'
    NICEBUTDIM = 'NICE'
    OLDATHEART = 'OLDA'
    PERFECTED = 'PERF'
    PLAIN = 'PLAI'
    POISONOUSBREATH = 'POIS'
    PRIZESPECIMAN = 'PRIZ'
    PRODUCER = 'PROD'
    RADIANT = 'RADI'
    RAVENSWORN = 'RAVE'
    REGULAR = 'REGU'
    ROBUST = 'ROBU'
    SHOCKBREATH = 'SHOC'
    SICKLY = 'SICK'
    SLOWPOKE = 'SLOW'
    SMELLY = 'SMEL'
    SPARKLING = 'SPAR'
    STINGY = 'STIN'
    STRESSED = 'STRE'
    STRONGGENES = 'STRO'
    STUDLY = 'STUD'
    SULLEN= 'SULL'
    SURLY = 'SURL'
    TAKER = 'TAKE'
    UNLUCKYFORSOME = 'UNLU'
    VIRILE = 'VIRI'
    YOUNGATHEART = 'YOUN'
    NONE = 'NONE'
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
    ]
    AGE_CHOICES = [
        (EGG, 'Egg'),
        (CHILD, 'Child'),
        (ADOLESCENT, 'Adolescent'),
        (ADULT, 'Adult'),
        (ELDER, 'Elder'),
    ]
    SHINY_CHOICES = [
        (SHINY, 'Shiny'),
        (NORMAL, 'Normal'),
    ]
    FIRST_TRAIT_CHOICES = [
        (BIGBONED, 'Big Boned'),
        (CONSTIPATED, 'Constipated'),
        (FUSSYEATER, 'Fussy Eater'),
        (GENETICINFERIORITY, 'Genetic Inferiority'),
        (GENETICMUTATION, 'Genetic Mutation'),
        (GIVER, 'Giver'),
        (HANDSOME, 'Handsome'),
        (HYPERACTIVE, 'Hyperactive'),
        (JOVIAL, 'Jovial'),
        (JOYFUL, 'Joyful'),
        (LUCKY, 'Lucky'),
        (OLDATHEART, 'Old at Heart'),
        (PLAIN, 'Plain'),
        (PRODUCER, 'Producer'),
        (REGULAR, 'Regular'),
        (ROBUST, 'Robust'),
        (SICKLY, 'Sickly'),
        (SLOWPOKE, 'Slowpoke'),
        (SPARKLING, 'Sparkling'),
        (STINGY, 'Stingy'),
        (STRESSED, 'Stressed'),
        (STUDLY, 'Studly'),
        (SULLEN, 'Sullen'),
        (SURLY, 'Surly'),
        (VIRILE, 'Virile'),
        (YOUNGATHEART, 'Young at Heart'),
        ]
    SECOND_TRAIT_CHOICES = [
        (NONE, 'None'),
        (CHARMED, 'Charmed'),
        (CHATTY, 'Chatty'),
        (EVIL, 'Evil'),
        (GENETICINSTABILITY, 'Genetic Instability'),
        (GENETICMUTATION, 'Genetic Mutation'),
        (GENIUS, 'Genius'),
        (GIVER, 'Giver'),
        (GLISTENING, 'Glistening'),
        (GOOD, 'Good'),
        (GOODBREEDING, 'Good Breeding'),
        (HANDSOME, 'Handsome'),
        (HYPERACTIVE, 'Hyperactive'),
        (IMMUNE, 'Immune'),
        (INSANE, 'Insane'),
        (JOVIAL, 'Jovial'),
        (JOYFUL, 'Joyful'),
        (LUCKY, 'Lucky'),
        (MYSTERIOUS, 'Mysterious'),
        (PERFECTED, 'Perfected'),
        (PRODUCER, 'Producer'),
        (RAVENSWORN, 'Ravensworn'),
        (ROBUST, 'Robust'),
        (SMELLY, 'Smelly'),
        (SPARKLING, 'Sparkling'),
        (STRONGGENES, 'Strong Genes'),
        (STUDLY, 'Studly'),
        (VIRILE, 'Virile'),
        ]
    THIRD_TRAIT_CHOICES = [
        (NONE, 'None'),
        (BUTTERFACE, 'Butterface'),
        (CHARMED, 'Charmed'),
        (CURVY, 'Curvy'),
        (EXALTED, 'Exalted'),
        (FORTUNATE, 'Fortunate'),
        (FREAKOFNATURE, 'Freak of Nature'),
        (GENETICINSTABILITY, 'Genetic Instability'),
        (GENETICMUTATION, 'Genetic Mutation'),
        (GIVER, 'Giver'),
        (GLISTENING, 'Glistening'),
        (GOLDENGIFT, 'Golden Gift'),
        (GOODBREEDING, 'Good Breeding'),
        (IMMUNE, 'Immune'),
        (JOYFUL, 'Joyful'),
        (LIMITEDEFFICIENCY, 'Limited Efficiency'),
        (LITHE, 'Lithe'),
        (LUCKY, 'Lucky'),
        (MYSTERIOUS, 'Mysterious'),
        (NICEBUTDIM, 'Nice But Dim'),
        (PERFECTED, 'Perfected'),
        (PRIZESPECIMAN, 'Prize Speciman'),
        (PRODUCER, 'Producer'),
        (RADIANT, 'Radiant'),
        (SPARKLING, 'Sparkling'),
        (STRONGGENES, 'Strong Genes'),
        (STUDLY, 'Studly'),
        (UNLUCKYFORSOME, 'Unlucky For Some'),
    ]
    # max_length refers to the length of the characters stored in the database, not the length of the trait
    gender_of_animal = models.CharField(
        max_length= 6,
        choices= GENDER_CHOICES,
        default=MALE,
    )
    shiny_or_not = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=SHINY_CHOICES,
        default=NORMAL,
    )
    age_of_animal = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=AGE_CHOICES,
        default=ADOLESCENT,
    )
    first_trait = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices=FIRST_TRAIT_CHOICES,
        default=SPARKLING,
    )
    second_trait = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices=SECOND_TRAIT_CHOICES,
        default=NONE,
    )
    third_trait = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices=THIRD_TRAIT_CHOICES,
        default=NONE,
    )
    #class Meta:
    #    abstract = True
class DRAGON(ANIMAL):
    FIRST_TRAIT_CHOICES + ((FROSTBREATH, 'Frost Breath'), (POISONOUSBREATH, 'Poisonous Breath'), (SHOCKBREATH, 'Shock Breath',))
    SECOND_TRAIT_CHOICES += ((FROSTBREATH, 'Frost Breath'), (POISONOUSBREATH, 'Poisonous Breath'), (SHOCKBREATH, 'Shock Breath',))
    THIRD_TRAIT_CHOICES += ((FROSTBREATH, 'Frost Breath'), (POISONOUSBREATH, 'Poisonous Breath'), (SHOCKBREATH, 'Shock Breath',))
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is okay if you want your dragons to be separate from other animals, but I get the feeling you might not want this. Say you want to get all animals, you couldn't just do `Animal.objects.all()`, you would have to do `Dragon.objects.all(), ...` etc. for each one.

I would recommend the following restructuring:

1. Move all of your choices into separate models, there are just way too many in my opinion and they are both repetitive and hardcoded.

```py
# Instead of 
FIRST_TRAIT_CHOICES = [
    (BIGBONED, 'Big Boned'),
    ... etc.

# do
class Trait(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...
    animal_types = models.ManyToManyField(... 
    # ^ m2m as many animals can have many trains
```

2. Note the `animal_types` field above - create another model that captures the type of animal, e.g. a Dragon:

```py
class AnimalType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(... # e.g. Dragon, etc.
```

3. Then attach this to your animal model - you can also do this for you traits. It makes it far more manageable and dynamic, also removing a lot of bloat from your model code.

```py
class Animal(models.Model):
    animal_type = models.ForeignKey(AnimalType, ...
    first_trait = models.ForeignKey(Trait, ...
    ... etc.
```

Going back to your traits, you can create logic to ensure only certain animal types can have certain traits.

This makes your code much cleaner, you're pushing all of the data into the database which makes it more easily editable. It also means that if ever the traits or animal types change then you don't have to bulk update charfields, you just change the database entry.

Finally, you can get all dragons like this, without removing the ability to have dragons and other animals together in a queryset:

```py
dragons = Animal.objects.filter(animal_type__name="dragon")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this looks like exactly what I had in mind, but I'm a bit confused on how to properly fill out the information  `class Trait(models.model):
     name = models.CharField((LITHE, 'Lithe'),(LUCKY, 'Lucky'),)
     animal_types = models.ManytoManyField(confused about this part)

    # class AnimalType(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(Dragon, Chicken)

    class Animal(models.Model):
     animal_type = models.ForeignKey(AnimalType,'what other information here')
     first_trait = models.ForeignKey(Trait,'or here' )'` for gender, etc, i put after this?

Comment: Edit - just seen your edit, bear with me

Comment: So your `Trait` and `AnimalType` models wouldn't have choices (unless you reeeally need to hardcode these), instead you create these objects as normal in the database. So a Lithe object, Lucky object, etc. and then your Animal object can get those values as relations

Comment: It finally clicked for me as I was thinking about it last night.  Can the objects be created with the django admin portal somehow, and should I store the special traits that only 1 animal holds, such as "frost breath" for dragons or "baroo" for yaks in a special separate table, or would it be better to just make a master traits table?

Comment: That’s exactly it - create these models in the admin and manage them there. I would set a field on the Trait model that determines which animal types it can be associated with or not

Comment: I've finally got it going, things are looking good, but I'd like to be able to restrict the placement of traits, as all of the traits aren't possible in all positions, as in lithe lithe lithe. The "lithe" trait in the game can only be held in trait position 3. Would you suggest the use of "limit_choices_to", or is there a slightly more elegant method? (as that one would result in a bit more hardcoding) Thanks so much for your help btw, I'm learning a lot

Comment: Add a field called ‘slots’ to your Trait model and let it be nullable. Check the field when a trait is added, if it’s null then a trait can go anywhere, otherwise abide by the field value. I would do something like a charfield with “123”, for it can go anywhere, “12” for first and second only etc. your logic becomes really easy: if “2” in field (aka “12”) then accept trait in position two

Comment: ` class Trait(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    animal_types = models.ManyToManyField(AnimalType)
    slots = models.CharField(default=None, null=True, max_length=4)
    #def TraitPlace(self): `  Spent a few hours trying to figure out how this could work, couldn't quite figure what to use, tried hasattr() but couldn't quite figure out placement.  Currently I've got the function under my traits model but I'm not quite sure if that's the right place for it, or how to format it so that when animal model is used that it checks trait slot. Would love some guidance